# Why is my Peltier module hot on both sides?

Tags: peltier, cooling, overheat

I've bought a TEC-12706 and used a 12V battery. I attached heatsinks and fans on both sides. The two sides get very hot as soon as I apply electricity to it.

Comment: Looks like you need a heat sink in the hot side. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/115531/thermoelectric-couple-heating-on-both-sides

Answer (score 12):

Peltiers turn a lot more power into heat than they manage to pump heat.

Than means, that the ambient-side heat capacity must always be much greater than the pumped-side heat load.

If you attach equal heatsinks on both sides, you will experience thermal runaway as you noticed.

If you remove **one of the heatsinks**, you will notice that the remaining heatsink stays approximately near the ambient temperature, while the pumped side of the Peltier cools/heats considerably, depending on the current direction.